# How to remove a piece of HTML tags in a HTML page using PHP

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have a situation. I read in a html page using php using this piece of code `$body = file_get_contents('index.htm');`

Now in the index.htm file is a piece of html code like below that I sometimes need to remove/depends on criteria, so sometimes it needs to be removed and other times not.

```
<td><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></td>
```

How do I remove the whole **table** section between the **td** tags using **PHP**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it can be

```
$str = '<td><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></td>';
preg_match('/(<td>)(<table>.*<\/table>)(<\/td>)/',$str,$matches);
```

the resulting array

```
Array
(
    [0] => <td><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></td>
    [1] => <td>
    [2] => <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    [3] => </td>
)
```

can be used to recreate the

```
 '<td></td>'
```

without the table section

Comment: Your solution does not work if the TD has attributes, or the TABLE.

Comment: You are right, but he didn't specify in the question that he had attributes, however the regexp can be adatpted to deal with variable attrs, or (as I suppose) the html that he needs to remove is always of the same kind, so he can hardcode attributes in the regexp.

Answer (score 2):

If you are lucky enough that your page is XML then you could form a DOM and remove the  from the DOM. Otherwise a regular expression should be easy as long as you don't have nested `<table>`s (in which case it's still possible but more tricky).

Comment: You can get at nesting too if you use recursion lookaround.

Comment: Er, recursion *and* lookaround. Of course those aren't strictly "regular", they're PCRE extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the **table** between **td**'s using a regular expression replacement.

```
$html=preg_replace('/<td([^>]*)><table[^>]*>.*<\/table><\/td>/', '<td$1></td>', $html);
```

This also works if you have attributes in your  or in your

*I tried it myself ([RegEx Tester](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/)) and it works, hope it also works for you.*